# Defense against common security threat for Desktop Application

Tags: c++, security, desktop-application

I am developing a username/password based desktop application in c++ which also communicates with my server. Currently ignoring threat on the wire, I want to know the threat there are on the users system and how to prevent from them?
E.g Keyloggers, print screen etc

Comment: @Code: First 20m of wire free, then please buy our WireSafe(tm) subscription!

Comment: Typically the biggest threat is the user - now if we could get rid of them... ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are [10 Immutable Laws of Security](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722487.aspx)

One of them states: if the "bad guy" has physical access to your computer, it can't consider it to be safe anymore. Period.

All measures that people will tell you here (against screen capture, keyloggers, etc) can be overcome by someone who that traps some hardware between the keyboard and the motherboard, or attach something to read your RAM, or boot by some system and them run your program on that specific (and deteriorated) OS...

Answer (score 1):

Larry Osterman wrote up a pretty good [series on threat modeling](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2007/08/30/threat-modeling-once-again.aspx).  It can be a tedious exercise, but it'll help clarify your thinking about what the threats are and where you can erect defenses.  Perhaps it'll help you form a more specific question that will generate more useful answers.